# Pyspark - UDF function right after column creation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to apply an UDF function just after a column has been created.

But I got the issue :

`Cannot resolve column name "previous_status" among`

Which means that the column doesn't exist.

I could probably modify the UDF function in order to not be an UDF anymore and just a normal function with `F.when` & `otherwise`. The thing is I need a global dict as you can see to determine whether I've already seen that id or not.

```
alreadyAuthorized = {}

def previously_authorized_spark(id, failed, alreadyAuthorized = alreadyAuthorized):
    if id in alreadyAuthorized:
        previously_authorized = 1
    else:
        previously_authorized = 0

    if not failed:
        alreadyAuthorized[id] = True

    return previously_authorized

previously_authorized_udf = udf(lambda x, y : previously_authorized_spark(x, y), IntegerType())

def get_previous_status(data):
    partition = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")

    data = data.withColumn("previous_status", F.lag(F.col("failed")).over(partition))\
                .withColumn("previously_authorized", previously_authorized_udf(data["id"], data["previous_status"]))

data = get_previous_status(data)
```

Comment: You're referring to `data["previous_status"]` within the assignment to `data`. So the column does not exist at this point. 
If you divide it into to steps, it should work.

Comment: I've already tried to divided it I guess the `data` columns will exist only if I do an execute function like `count`, `show` or something but I don't want to do it because it won't be optimized by Spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `col` function to get column, because as @LaSul pointed out, you use `data` before it was assigned:

```py
from pyspark.sql.function import col

...
    data = data.withColumn("previous_status", F.lag(F.col("failed")).over(partition))\
                .withColumn("previously_authorized", previously_authorized_udf(col("id"), col("previous_status")))

...
```

Comment: Worked well, :) I though about that but did not though it would work since it's of type Column